# Recursive CTEs to pull BOM (Bill of Material)

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I need some assistance or pointer on CTEs.
I am trying to extract Bill of Material and I have used CTEs query. The query works good and it pulls all the data. My struggle is there are lot of parts where the parts has new version on different levels and I want to grab new versions only. Currently my query grabs everything. I have a version column.
I tried few different things like trying to utilize max function within CTEs but I got an error saying group by, having cannot be part of recursive ctes.
Also, I tried using subquery but I didnt get the right result.

```
WITH BOM (
    Parent
    ,Child
    ,Qty
    ,Childrev
    ,LEVEL   
    ,sort
    )
AS (
    SELECT Parent
        ,cast(RTRIM(Child) AS NVARCHAR(max))
        ,Qty
        ,Childrev
        ,0 AS LEVEL
        ,cast(RTRIM(Child) AS NVARCHAR(max))
    FROM Bomtable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT BOM.Parent
        ,cast(RTRIM(Bomtable.Child) AS NVARCHAR(max))
        ,Bomtable.Qty
        ,BOM.Childrev
        ,LEVEL + 1
        ,CAST(BOM.Sort + '..... ' + RTRIM(Bomtable.Child) AS NVARCHAR(max))
    FROM BOM
    INNER JOIN Bomtable ON Bomtable.Parent = BOM.Child
    WHERE BOM.Parent = main product
    ORDER BY SORT
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I do not fully understand your data model. However, try replacing your **BOM** and **BomTable** tables with a derived table like this which will give you one row for each Child record with the greatest Childrev value without using a GROUP BY.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT *
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Child ORDER BY Childrev DESC) AS ROW_NBR
           FROM   BOM
       ) AS x
WHERE  x.ROW_NBR = 1;
```

Here is the documentation for the the [OVER Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Noel